# Gene Complementation Question

Tags: homework, molecular-genetics, genetics, allele

[image]

Hi everyone! Here is a diagram of a genetics complementation problem. My main concern is regarding number 3d. I'm assuming that in this case, it would be complementary interaction and thus exhibiting a ratio of nine to seven. because if we cross F1, 3 will be mutant while one will exhibit wild-type phenotype. Is this right? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes 9:7 seems to be the right answer.

F1 progeny should be AaGg... and crossing it will give a ratio of 9:7 as is of any complementary genes